# OpenCV Fullscreen Output -> Illegal Instruction

Tags: python, opencv

I have Raspian with the Raspberry camera and small Monitor connected via rca.
Now I want to display the captured image in Fullscreen Mode.

```
import cv2
cv2.namedWindow("Frame", cv2.WND_PROP_FULLSCREEN)
#cv2.setWindowProperty("Frame", cv2.WND_PROP_FULLSCREEN, cv2.WINDOW_FULLSCREEN)

#while caputering
    cv2.imshow("Frame", image)
    key = cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF

    if key == ord("q"):
       break
```

When uncommenting the setWindowProperty Line, the program crashes with the output "Illigal instruction". Without the line it works perfect.

OpenCV 3.2
Python 3.4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved. I had the default GUI for Raspbian installed: PIXEL.

Now I installed MATE over an light image of Raspbian without xserver. Works perfect